# intent filter android with all gps apps

Tags: android, gps

I want to do an intent filter with all gps apps installed in device.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068910/android-intent-filter), but now, how I get the gps apps installed in device?

Anyone knows?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A crude, but the only, way would be to scan all the packages for apps that request the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission.

This will give you a list of the apps that *can* use the GPS. It doesn't guarantee that they *do* use the GPS.

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager(); 
final List<PackageInfo> apps = p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
for (PackageInfo pkg : apps) {
    for (String permission : pkg.requestedPermissions) {
        // Check if permission is the ACCURACY FINE permission
    }
}
```

Comment: I just put this: Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=an+address+city"));